# Cannot figure out how to format strings in an array (C) – very new to comp sci

Tags: arrays, c, string, string-formatting, cs50

I've looked through many questions here, but the syntax is unfamiliar to me. I am trying to write a program in C, that given a composer's name, will give you the instrumentation that composer used in orchestral music. I am trying to figure out how to format strings in an array, but the compiler won't recognize them. I have tried using one variable, no luck. Right now, only errors from compiler are "undeclared identifiers" for each indexed composer's name in j[0], j[1], j[2]. So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Henlo, (')> I will determine your average orchestral instrumentation per composer.\n");
    printf("Your options are: JS_Bach, Mozart, Beethoven, Brahms, Wagner, R_Strauss, Ravel, and Debussy.\n");

    string i = get_string("Composer: "); //get_string (from <cs50.h> prompts the user to enter text

    string j[8];
        j[0] = JS_Bach; //undeclared identifiers for j[0] thru j[7]
        j[1] = Mozart;
        j[2] = Beethoven;
        j[3] = Brahms;
        j[4] = Wagner;
        j[5] = R_Strauss;
        j[7] = Ravel;
        j[7] = Debussy;

    if (i == j[0])
    {
        printf("2fl, 2-3ob, maybe d'amore/da caccia, 3trp, timp, vln.I, vln.II, vla, SATB choir + solo, bc\n");
    }
    else if (i == j[1])
    {
        printf("1-2fl, 2ob, maybe 2cl/basset 2bsn, 2hrn, 2trp, timp, vln.I, vln.II, vla, vlc, cb\n");

//same format with different text in printf for j[2] thru j[7], (won't waste space here with the rest)
```

I have also seen questions with code using `char**` and things like that; could someone explain the asterisk's purpose? Do I need to declare items as `char` instead of `string`? The type `string` is defined by `<cs50.h>`. Not sure if I will need another function library to use strings in arrays?

Comment: You are referring to the names as identifiers and not as constants like you want them to be. Change Wagner to "Wagner".

Comment: Use double quote around your string like this: `j[0] = "JS_Bach";`. It should be okay after that.

Comment: You can't compare strings in C with `if (i == j[0])`, please use `if (strcmp(i, j[0]) == 0)`

Comment: Formatting ouput with `printf()` can be quite involved. Best thing is to spend an hour with the man pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the names as identifiers and not as constants like you want them to be. Change `Wagner` to `"Wagner"` for example. You get an error because these identifiers were never defined before being used by you.

Also, right now when you are comparing the strings you are comparing their addresses in memory. Consider using `strcmp` if you want to compare the strings and not their addresses.

Comment: Thank you!! This all helped me compile and run successfully. I guess if strcmp(//two strings) == 0 that means they correspond correctly?